# TextView on ImageView is not Working in Fragment

Tags: android

I want to put text on an image view and try to display it in fragment.I got the output when I am working the same task using activities. I failed when I tried to use fragments. Can any one tell me how to do this in fragments.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent){
    if(view ==null){LayoutInflater     inflater=LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    holder.imgfile =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    holder.title=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    holder.title.setText(custgridfragdata.get(positiong).get("channelname"));
    Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"MTCORSVA.TTF");
    holder.title.setTypeface(font);
    view.setTag(holder);
    }else{holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();}
    return view;}
```

I am defining them in `getView` from defining a local **adapterclass**. In that adapter class I am defining the layout elements. I am using `GridView` in fragment. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    GView =  new GridView(getActivity());
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    GView.setNumColumns(3);
    }
    gridfragdata=MainActivity.userselected; 
    GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata));
    return GView;
    }
```

Here I defined a layout with ImageView and TextView on ImageView. I want to display the text on an image. As I am using fragements with GridView, I want to get them from layout and display in fragment. To do so, I defined an Adapter Class, in that adapter class from `GetView()` method I am getting the elements from xml. I am setting the Apater to GridView object as;

```
GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata));
```

In fragment as we don't need to define Xml for GridView

```
GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata));
```

here `R.layout.grid_item` is the Xml file containing image and text

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_18" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="@color/green"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/cream"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/GridFont" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code then....

Comment: I think you forgot to give a reference of your View object for casting your UI views. So show your code.

Comment: I think you should show your code so somebody will answer on this question and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreateView(...)` method, need to use View object, e.g

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browsematerialdocument, null);

    ImageView imgV= (ImageView ) view
            .findViewById(R.id.imgv_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm defining them in `getView` from defining a local adapter class and in that adapter class am defining the layout elements.and am using `GridView` in fragment. My code is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    GView =  new GridView(getActivity());
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    GView.setNumColumns(3);
    }
    gridfragdata=MainActivity.userselected; 
    GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata));
    return GView;
}
```

Comment: hi ker,here i defined a layout with ImageView and TextView on ImageView.i want to display the text on image.as am using fragements with GridView,i want to get them from layout and display in fragment.for that i defined an Adapter Class,in that adapter class from GetView()method am getting the elements from xml.so am setting the Apater to GridView object as  GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata));

Comment: But in onCreateView where did you set your xml file in which ur gridview?

Comment: in fragment we dnt need to define Xml for GridView and in  GView.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(),R.layout.grid_item, gridfragdata)); R.layout.grid_item is the Xml file containing image and text

Comment: Show your xml file and your adapter class with edit ur question